# Design pattern to use to populate multiple class fields

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a use case where I have to parse an XML document and fill details in a corresponding fields of an internal model POJO `Details`.
Let's say, the XML look like following -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

...
<TagA>
 <Child1>
 ...
 </Child1>
 <Child2>
 ...
 </Child2>
</TagA>

...

<TagB>
 <Child1>
 ...
 </Child1>
 <Child2>
 ...
 </Child2>
</TagB>
....
```

And the internal model POJO looks like following -

```
public class Details {

...

Set<TagAInfo> tagAInformation; 
Set<TagBInfo> tagBInformation;

...

}
```

The XML has multiple fields like TagAs, TagBs etc.

**Current implementation:** So currently there is a mapper/parser class(let's say `Mapper.java`) that calls multiple methods like `mapTagAInfo(details, xmlRootElement)`, `mapTagBInfo(details, xmlRootElement)` etc. on `details`(i.e. instance of `Details.java`) something like following -

```
public class Mapper {
 ....

public Details mapInfo(XmlElement xmlRootElement) {
  Details details = new Details();
  mapTagAInfo(details, xmlRootElement)
  mapTagBInfo(details, xmlRootElement)
  mapTagCInfo(details, xmlRootElement)
 ....
 return details;
}

private void mapTagAInfo(details, xmlRootElement) {
  stp1: Extract <TagA> tag element info using a utility which reads the xml document
  stp2: use the stp1 info and convert to internal model POJO TagAInfo and 
  add to details (details.addTagAInfo(tagAInfo))
}
```

**Question:** The current implementation makes the code look very ugly(as in a single class `Mapper.java` multiple things are happening), so wanted to know if I can use some design pattern to improve the code ? If so, please suggest what design pattern to use and an example explaining the design pattern usage would help a lot.

**Update:** The project uses Dom4j to read XML. Also, the question was more around handling the responsibilities of the mapper class. As one can see, it has lot of functions like mapTagAInfo, mapTagBInfo etc. Wanted to know if I should delegate the responsibilities to different classes - eg. TagAInfoEnricher, TagBInfoEnricher etc. If yes, then how to do it, what design pattern to use etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Unmarshalling with JAXB.

Examples:

- https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-unmarshaller-example/
- https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/read-xml-to-java-object/

Comment: The project uses Dom4j to read XML. Also, the question was more around handling the responsibility of the mapper class. As one can see, it has lot of functions like mapTagAInfo, mapTagBInfo etc. Wanted to know if I should delegate the responsibilities to different classes - eg. TagAInfoEnricher, TagBInfoEnricher etc. If yes, then how to do it, what design pattern to use etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually like using the builder pattern, Lombok @Builder annotation, to create my objects.

```
@Builder
@Getter
class Details implements Serializable {

  Set<TagAInfo> tagAInformation; 
  Set<TagBInfo> tagBInformation;

  public static void mapTagAInfo(details, xmlRootElement) {
    ...
  }
 }
```

The other design pattern I like to use is creating Static method inside the class to construct my objects especially DTOs

Don't know if this helps

Comment: Please see the updated question.